# Sort list of dictionaries based on values with highest similarity

Tags: python, sorting, go

Given the following python list of dictionaries:

```
results = [[{'id': '001', 'result': [0,0,0,0,1]},
           {'id': '002', 'result': [1,1,1,1,1]},
           {'id': '003', 'result': [0,1,1,None,None]},
           {'id': '004', 'result': [0,None,None,1,0]},
           {'id': '005', 'result': [1,0,None,1,1]},
           {'id': '006', 'result': [0,0,0,1,1]}],
          [{'id': '001', 'result': [1,0,1,0,1]},
           {'id': '002', 'result': [1,1,1,1,1]},
           {'id': '003', 'result': [0,1,1,None,None]},
           {'id': '004', 'result': [0,None,None,1,0]},
           {'id': '005', 'result': [1,0,None,1,1]},
           {'id': '006', 'result': [1,0,1,0,1]}]
            ]
```

I would like to generate a new sorted list (in both python and golang) based on the values of 'result' by comparing results between the players ('id') in each group and then sorting them based on the number of matching entries (None results are discarded and not counted):

During the first round and second round 001 and 006 had nine matching answers:
001 = [0,0,0,0,1]   006 = [0,0,0,1,1] - four matching answers.
During the second round, 001 and 006 had five matching answers:
001 = [1,0,1,0,1]   006 = [1,0,1,0,1] - five matching answers

```
sorted_results = ['001','006','002','005','003','004']
```

'001' and '006' are the first two items in the list because they have the highest number of matching results - nine.

Comment: It would probably be a good start to write a function that computes the similarity between two lists according to your definition of "similar".

Comment: Shouldn't 002 come first and then 001 and then 006?

Comment: The question just got even more confusing after your edit, in addition to the Python snippet now containing a 2-tuple of lists as opposed to just a list before.

Comment: Yes, thank you for having a look. I have tried to clarify to the best of my ability.

Comment: @Pacifico: So it's actually supposed to be a 2-tuple of lists now?

Comment: @ErikAllik: I attempted to describe results as a list containing two lists each with a list of dictionary items. Apologies if my syntax is faulty. results[0][2]['id'] = '003'

Answer (score 1):

If you sort those items by the "highest number of identical results", this is what you get:

```
['003', '004', '005', '006', '001', '002']
```

If you meant something else (i.e. not "highest number of identical results"), please clarify your question. Also, you can simply modify the `max_identical` function so that it acts according to your definition of similar.

The above result was computed with:

```
from collections import defaultdict


results = [{'id': '001', 'result': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]},
           {'id': '002', 'result': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]},
           {'id': '003', 'result': [0, 1, 1, None, None]},
           {'id': '004', 'result': [0, None, None, 1, 0]},
           {'id': '005', 'result': [1, 0, None, 1, 1]},
           {'id': '006', 'result': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]}]


def max_identical(lst):
    counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for x in lst:
        if x is not None:
            counts[x] += 1
    return max(counts.values())


results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: max_identical(x['result']))

print [x['id'] for x in results]
```

Comment: I have updated my post in an attempt to clarify that each id's result will be compared to the others to determine which id's have the most identical results across multiple iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution for a problem very similar to yours I found this page:
http://w3facility.org/question/sorting-a-python-dictionary-after-running-an-itertools-function/

Using your example:

```
import itertools
results = [[{'id': '001', 'result': [0,0,0,0,1]},
           {'id': '002', 'result': [1,1,1,1,1]},
           {'id': '003', 'result': [0,1,1,None,None]},
           {'id': '004', 'result': [0,None,None,1,0]},
           {'id': '005', 'result': [1,0,None,1,1]},
           {'id': '006', 'result': [0,0,0,1,1]}],
          [{'id': '001', 'result': [1,0,1,0,1]},
           {'id': '002', 'result': [1,1,1,1,1]},
           {'id': '003', 'result': [0,1,1,None,None]},
           {'id': '004', 'result': [0,None,None,1,0]},
           {'id': '005', 'result': [1,0,None,1,1]},
           {'id': '006', 'result': [1,0,1,0,1]}]
          ]
```

This will create an all vs all comparison of the ids, each for for each round.

```
similarity = {}
for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(results[0], 2):
    similarity.setdefault((p1["id"], p2["id"]), sum([1 for i in range(len(p1["result"])) if p1["result"][i] == p2["result"][i]]))
for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(results[1], 2):
    similarity.setdefault((p1["id"], p2["id"]), 0)
    similarity[(p1["id"], p2["id"])] += sum([1 for i in range(len(p1["result"])) if p1["result"][i] == p2["result"][i]])
```

Now to sort the ids pairs by their matching values, will return a list of ordered tuples of ids.

```
similarity = sorted(similarity, key=lambda x:similarity[x], reverse=True)
print(similarity)
```

Now to eliminate the duplicate values, it is just necessary to retain the first occurence of each id, in that order and forget of the rest.

```
sorted_ids = []
for tuple_id in similarity:
    if tuple_id[0] not in sorted_ids:
        sorted_ids.append(tuple_id[0])
    if tuple_id[1] not in sorted_ids:
        sorted_ids.append(tuple_id[1])

print sorted_ids
```